# ios - makes appear all cell delete button by an action

Tags: ios, tableview

I have a table view (filled by customs cells) and my idea is have a tabbar button (such as "edit button"). Pressing on it, in all row, the button cancell will appear.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the code for the button (you know... `UIButton* button = [UIButton alloc]init];`) in your cell and set it to `Hidden = YES`, then add a `BOOL` to check if the "edit button" was pressed, lets name it `BOOL editActive`, then when the button is pressed you will check the `editActive`, if its `NO` then the `Hidden` value of the button will be `NO` and you reload your table with `[yourTableView reloadData]`, otherwise, if `editActive = YES`, then you must hide your "Cancel button" in the cell and once again use `[yourTableView reloadData]`

Comment: If you use a XIB then you just need to create the button on the IB and link it to a `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton* editButton;` instead of creating the button programmatically